# Clock with powerdot and beamer

Tags: beamer, datetime, powerdot

I would like to use powerdot to compose a document.  I want to have a clock in the pdf file, but it does not show. If I am using Beamer, then how can I have a clock as in powerdot?  Please help me.

```
\documentclass[size=12pt,
% style=husky,
% style= default
% style= elcolors
  style=tycja,
  paper=screen,
  mode =present,
  orient=landscape,
  display = slidesnotes,
  nopagebreaks,fleqn,clockformat]{powerdot}

\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{First}
    Let $ABC$ be a triangle.
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `clock` option instead of `clockformat`.

Comment: And with `beamer`, you can use the `tdclock` package.

Comment: I used clock, but I can not  run.This is log file
http://www.mediafire.com/?20o0771wny12h8w

Comment: Maybe a bug with your version of `hyperref`: your version is `v6.79k`; my version is `v6.83g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `powerdot`, you can:

- use the `clock` option,
- compile via `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`,
- and use a PDF Viewer with Javascript capacity (like *Adobe Reader*).

```
\documentclass[size=12pt,
  style=tycja,
  paper=screen,
  mode =present,
  orient=landscape,
  display = slidesnotes,
  nopagebreaks,fleqn,clock]{powerdot}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide}{First}
    Let $ABC$ be a triangle.
\end{slide}
\end{document}
```

With `beamer`, you can:

- use the `tdclock` package,
- compile via `pdflatex`,
- and use a PDF Viewer with Javascript capacity (like *Adobe Reader*).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[timeinterval=1,font=Helv]{tdclock}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\hspace{.5em}\textcolor{red}{\tiny\bfseries\tdtime}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \initclock
  \frametitle{First slide}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Second slide}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The beamer example produces red framed boxes instead of working clock in AR 9.

Comment: @AlexG Here it's ok with Adobe Reader 9.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I am using up-to-date TeXLive-2012, AR-9.5.1 on Gentoo.

Comment: With original `tdclock.sty`, the clock in a second document open, such as `tdclock-doc.pdf`, will not work. I first opened `tdclock` documentation and then the beamer example.

Answer (score 2):

Due to a bug in `tdclock.sty`, the clocks in more than one PDF opened in AR do not work except for the clock in the document opened first.

These are the steps to get clocks inserted using `tdclock` always working:

```
sed -i '/^global\.[ifd]/ s/^/%/' tdclock.sty
sed -i 's/global\.//g' tdclock.sty
sed -i 's/TextField\[/TextField\[readonly,/g' tdclock.sty
```

[image: orig. tdclock.sty] [image: patched tdclock.sty]

Comment: What do I need to change to make it work on a Windows box with Cygwin?

Comment: Ok, but where do I use these commands? In the preamble of my TeX file? Could you give more details?

Comment: `tdclock` is not needed anymore for inserting a digtal clock in `powerdot`. `powerdot` comes with its own implementation. Just add `clock` as option to `\documentclass`. The time format can be further adjusted. If you want for example get rid of the (distracting) seconds, add `\pdsetup{clockformat=H:MM, clockrefresh=60000}` or `\pdsetup{clockformat=h:MM tt, clockrefresh=60000}`  in the preamble.

Comment: For `beamer`, you still need `tdclock`. Here you must patch `tdclock.sty`. These commands work in Unix environments to modify text files on the command line. Alternatively, open `tdclock.sty` in a text editor and do the modifications there. `sed 's/<orig text>/<replacement text>/g'` means: globally substitute `<orig text>` with `<replacemenrt text>`. The special chars make up Regular Expressions for pattern matching.