# Problem with boxes in tdclock

Tags: beamer, datetime

I have a problem with `tdclock`. In [one post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76145) I saw, it can be replace ved by some commands. Can anyone help me how to do that? Do I need to put those commands in CMD or some other place? Please help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What can be removed? Please post an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: By "removed" you probably mean "replaced"...

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

The issues reported here have been fixed by the package authors in the recent version 2.5 (2014-02-21). There should no longer be the need for the manual changes listed below.

---

This is a bug in `tdclock`: Whenever two documents with active clocks are opened at the same time in AdobeReader, at least one of them doesn't render the clock correctly.

Another annoyance is the shaded background of working clocks. This can be fixed by setting the text fields readonly in `tdclock.sty`.

[image: orig. tdclock.sty] [image: patched tdclock.sty]

To fix both issues, you can either apply the **patch file** listed below using `patch`, or by means of the `sed` commandline utility, as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76145. Both commands are available on standard Linux boxes and in the Cygwin environment for Windows PCs. `sed` is also available as a [standalone binary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files//sed/4.2.1/sed-4.2.1-setup.exe/download) for Windows that can be directly used in `CMD`.

```
--- tdclock.sty 2013-12-05 08:41:41.000000000 +0100
+++ tdclock.sty.fix 2013-12-05 08:43:00.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-\ProvidesPackage{tdclock} [2009/06/01 v2.2 clock accessory]
+\ProvidesPackage{tdclock} [2013/12/05 v2.3 clock accessory]

 %
 %  Luis Randez  randez@unizar.es
@@ -154,21 +154,21 @@

 \def\tdyear{%
 \clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
-\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[name=year, width=60pt, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize]{}}%
+\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true,name=year, width=60pt, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize]{}}%
 \vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-1pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 60pt{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}{\mbox{\TextField[name=year, width=60pt, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,readonly=true,
 value={}]{}\kern-60pt\kern \a@a pt\kern \b@b\clock@fontsize\kern \b@b\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
 }

 \def\pdfslash{%
 \clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
-\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[ width=60pt, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,value=/]{}}%
+\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true, width=60pt, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,value=/]{}}%
 \vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-0.75pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 60pt{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}{\mbox{\TextField[name=separatordate, width=60pt, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,
 readonly=true,value=/]{}\kern-60pt\kern \a@one pt\kern \b@one\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
 }

 \def\pdfcolon{%
 \clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
-\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,value=:]{}}%
+\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true,name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,value=:]{}}%
 \vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-0.4pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 0.90\clock@fontsize{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}{\raisebox{-\a@h pt}%
 {\mbox{\TextField[name=separatortime, width=0.90\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,
 readonly=true,value=:]{}\kern-0.90\clock@fontsize\kern\a@one pt\kern \b@one\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
@@ -176,7 +176,7 @@

 \def\clockfield#1{%
 \clock@setfonsize\clock@setheight\clock@setfontcolor%\clock@setwidth
-\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[name=#1, width=1.31\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize]{}}%
+\setbox\sizebox=\hbox{\TextField[readonly=true,name=#1, width=1.31\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize]{}}%
 \vrule width 0pt height 2pt\kern-\a@a pt\kern-\wd\sizebox\kern 1.31\clock@fontsize{\raisebox{-\b@h\clock@fontsize}%
 {\raisebox{-\a@h pt}{\mbox{\TextField[name=#1, width=1.31\clock@fontsize, height=\clock@height, align = 0, color =\clock@fontcolor, charsize = \clock@fontsize,readonly=true,
 value={}]{}\kern-1.31\clock@fontsize\kern\a@a pt\kern \b@b\clock@fontsize\vrule width 0pt height 2pt}}}}%
@@ -191,23 +191,23 @@

 \def\initfields{%
 \begin{Form}
-\mbox{\TextField[format=\startclock,name=resultado2, hidden=true, width=0truecm, height=0truecm, bordercolor= 1 1 1, backgroundcolor= 1 1 1,value={}]{}}
+\mbox{\TextField[readonly=true,format=\startclock,name=resultado2, hidden=true, width=0truecm, height=0truecm, bordercolor= 1 1 1, backgroundcolor= 1 1 1,value={}]{}}
 \end{Form}%
-%\TextField[name=resultado1, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}
-\TextField[name=hours, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=minutes, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=seconds, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=cronohours, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=cronominutes, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=crseconds, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=day, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=month, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
-\TextField[name=year, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+%\TextField[readonly=true,name=resultado1, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=hours, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=minutes, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=seconds, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=cronohours, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=cronominutes, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=crseconds, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=day, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=month, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=year, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt]{}%
 \PushButton[name=button1, onclick={\auxiliar;},hidden=true]{}%
 \PushButton[name=button2, onclick={\resetclock;},hidden=true]{}%
-\TextField[name=separatordate, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt, value=/]{}%
-\TextField[name=separatortime, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt, value=:]{}%
-\TextField[name=cronobox, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt, value= ]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=separatordate, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt, value=/]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=separatortime, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt, value=:]{}%
+\TextField[readonly=true,name=cronobox, hidden=true, width=0pt, height=0pt,charsize=0pt, value= ]{}%
 }

 \def\initclock{%
@@ -230,11 +230,11 @@
 %
 \def\startclock{%
 %
-global.iop;
-global.fuente;
-global.interval;
-global.duration;
-global.death;
+%iop;
+%fuente;
+%interval;
+%duration;
+%death;
 %
 var iop=1;
 var fuente=eval(\clock@font);
@@ -251,9 +251,9 @@
 function rresett()
 {
 var fObj0 = new Date();
-global.horas0 = fObj0.getHours();
-global.minutos0 = fObj0.getMinutes();
-global.segundos0 = fObj0.getSeconds();
+horas0 = fObj0.getHours();
+minutos0 = fObj0.getMinutes();
+segundos0 = fObj0.getSeconds();
 }
 %
 function alerta(kolor,kolorfill)
@@ -284,7 +284,7 @@
 minutos  = formateo(minutos);
 segundos = formateo(segundos);
 %
-resta = (eval(horas1-global.horas0)*60+eval(minutos1-global.minutos0))*60+eval(segundos1-global.segundos0);
+resta = (eval(horas1-horas0)*60+eval(minutos1-minutos0))*60+eval(segundos1-segundos0);
 h = Math.floor(resta/3600);        htexto=formateo(h);
 m = Math.floor((resta-3600*h)/60); mtexto=formateo(m);
 s = resta-3600*h-60*m;             stexto=formateo(s);
```